# Production-quality error handling in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, stack-trace

I'm working on request error handling in a node.js server application. I have defined a callback function handling these errors:

```
app.use(function errorHandler(err, req, res, next) {    
    res.send(err, {status: err, message: 'error'}); 

  }
);
```

which is fine for me as a developer, as it prints a stack trace like this:

```
{
"status": {
  "stack": "Error\\\n    at MongooseError.ValidationError (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:22:16)\\\n    at model.Document.invalidate (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1216:32)\\\n    at /home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1090:18\\\n    at validate (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:653:7)\\\n    at /home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:681:9\\\n    at Array.forEach (native)\\\n    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:658:19)\\\n    at /home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1088:11\\\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)",
  "message": "User validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError",
  "errors": {
    "email": {
      "properties": {
        "regexp": {},
        "type": "regexp",
        "message": "Path `{PATH}` is invalid ({VALUE}).",
        "path": "email",
        "value": "test@exa@mple.com"
      },
      "stack": "Error\\\n    at MongooseError.ValidatorError (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validator.js:25:16)\\\n    at validate (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:652:13)\\\n    at /home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:681:9\\\n    at Array.forEach (native)\\\n    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate (/home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:658:19)\\\n    at /home/osboxes/skipodium_rest_server/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1088:11\\\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)",
      "message": "Path `email` is invalid (test@exa@mple.com).",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "kind": "regexp",
      "path": "email",
      "value": "test@exa@mple.com"
    }
  }
},
"message": "error"
}
```

However, I'd like to display it in a neat, user-friendly format for the production version, without leaking the entire stack trace. Now I could specify the error status and message in every request handling function, but there is still specific information, like above, that the entered email is invalid, and I don't feel like typing it by hand for every single field that is checked by validator. Is there any existing boilerplate that will do the job for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose validation errors are a pain to handle. My general approach is to only take the first error (let the user deal with one at a time) and send the path and message since the rest won't really contribute much additional meaning to a non-developer.

```
first = err.errors[Object.keys(err.errors)[0]]
res.send({
    path: first.path,
    message: first.message
});
```

I'd also recommend having a custom API-style error format that you stick with for all of your errors- it will make maintainability much easier.

I have a set of pre-defined error templates that I rely on- here's one.

```
// If the client missed a required parameter
exports.missingParam = function (res, domain, param) {
   res.status(400).send({
      status: "failed",
      errors: [
         {
            status: "400",
            domain: domain,
            reason: "required",
            message: "Required parameter: "+param,
            locationType: "parameter",
            location: param
         }
      ]
   });
}
```

Comment: Or iterate over every child of `errors`. I was hoping for something even more automated, but that's a start I guess. Thanks!

Comment: If you only want the messages (which I found to be a bit too rudimentary), someone wrote this helper. https://github.com/syntagma/mongoose-error-helper